# Change font size on window width resize and change document height when font size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var fontSize = $('.basic_unit').css('font-size');
if (fontSize == '6px') {docHeight=32000;} else if (fontSize == '8px') {docHeight=48000;} else { docHeight = 11000; }

var winWidth = $(window).width();
if (winWidth <= 700){
 $('.basic_unit').css.('font-size','2px')
 }
 else if (winWidth > 701 && winWidth <= 1200) {
  $('.basic_unit').css.('font-size','6px') 
  }
 else 
 $('.basic_unit').css.('font-size','8px'); 
var variableXXX = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {

var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / docHeight;

 if ( scrollPercent >= 5 && variableXXX == false){
    variableXXX = true;
      alert($(document).scrollTop()); 
  }
});
```

I need this code to work as explained in the title:

- When window width is under 700 font size of the class is 2px.
- When    window width is between 700 and 1200 font size of the class
  is 6px.
- When window width is over 1200 font size of the class is 8px.

After this:

- When font size of the class is 2px docHeight is 11000px
- When font size of the class is 6px docHeight is 32000px
- When font size of the class is 8px docHeight is 48000px

After this:

- docHeight works in the scroll function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var winWidth = $(window).width();
if (winWidth <= 700){
    $('.basic_unit').css('font-size','2px')
    }
    else if (winWidth > 701 && winWidth <= 1200) {
        $('.basic_unit').css('font-size','6px') 
        }
    else 
    $('.basic_unit').css('font-size','8px'); 

});
```

But I suggest avoiding Javascript and doing it with css media:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .basic_unit {font-size:2px}
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 701px) and (max-device-width: 1200px) { 
       .basic_unit {font-size:6px}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1021px) {
        .basic_unit {font-size:8px}
}
```

Comment: thanks but it fails to trigger the third part of the code: var variableXXX = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
 
    var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / docHeight;
 
     if ( scrollPercent >= 5 && variableXXX == false){
        variableXXX = true;
          alert($(document).scrollTop()); 
      }
});

Comment: well it has nothing to with this part of the code. you must look for the error somewhere else. and I highly recommend using `@media screen`

Answer (score 1):

if you work for newer browsers, try `vw` and `vh` parameters:

```
font-size: 3vw
```

[Documentation W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)